# EventLogQuery invalid

Tags: c#, .net, event-log

I am trying to retrieve a specific Event by searching for a specific binary token.

Here is what I have:

```
var queryString = @"*[EventData[Binary='AAAD78D436708349A059D47F0CE766C4']]";
var query = new EventLogQuery('Application', PathType.LogName, queryString);
var results = new List<EventRecord>();
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                            {
                                using var reader = new EventLogReader(query);
                                while (reader.ReadEvent() is { } ev)
                                {
                                    results.Add(ev);
                                }
                            },
                            token);
return results;
```

Yes this specific string appears in the XML-View of the Event Viewer.  I have tried a variety of different combinations to get this to work and I always get an "Invalid Query" error.  Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

### Update 1

So I have also tried this:

```
var queryString = @"*[EventData[Binary and (Binary='AAAD78D436708349A059D47F0CE766C4')]]"
```

And this does not give me an error, but it also does not find the EventRecord (which is definitely in the EventLog).

Comment: Please add the XML from the XML view to your post.

Answer (score 0):

The following shows how one can search an [EventLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) to see if an entry exists that matches a specified binary value.

**Add the following using directives**:

- `using System.Xml.Linq;`
- `using System.Diagnostics;`
- `using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;`

**Note**: The following declarations are used in the methods below:

```
private static string _logName = "TestLog";
private static string _source = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location); //name of this project
```

**Option 1** (EventLogReader):

```
private List<EventRecord> SearchForEventRecordByDataStr(string logName, string data)
{
    List<EventRecord> eventRecords = new List<EventRecord>();

    using (EventLogReader reader = new EventLogReader(logName, PathType.LogName))
    {
        //create new instance
        EventRecord eventRecord = null;

        do
        {
            //read
            eventRecord = reader.ReadEvent();

            if (eventRecord == null)
                break;

            //parse XML
            XElement root = XElement.Parse(eventRecord.ToXml());

            string binaryData = root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Binary").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
            Debug.WriteLine($"binaryData: {binaryData}");
            
            if (data == binaryData)
            {
                //add
                eventRecords.Add(eventRecord);
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    return eventRecords;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
List<EventRecord> records = SearchForEventRecordByDataStr(_logName,"AAAD78D436708349A059D47F0CE766C4");
```

---

**Option 2**:

```
private List<EventLogEntry> SearchForLogEntryByDataStr(string logName, string source, string data)
{
    List<EventLogEntry> logEntries = new List<EventLogEntry>();

    using (EventLog eventLog1 = new EventLog() { Log = logName, Source = source })
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < eventLog1.Entries.Count; i++)
        {
            string entryDataStr = string.Empty;

            //convert binary data to how it's displayed in the Event Viewer
            //2-digit hex numbers without spaces
            foreach (byte b in eventLog1.Entries[i].Data)
            {
                entryDataStr += b.ToString("X2");
            }

            if (data == entryDataStr)
                logEntries.Add(eventLog1.Entries[i]); //add              
        }
    }

    return logEntries;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
List<EventLogEntry> eventLogEntries = SearchForLogEntryByDataStr(_logName, _source, "AAAD78D436708349A059D47F0CE766C4");
```

---

**Resources**:

- [EventLog Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)
- [EventLog.CreateEventSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.createeventsource?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)
- [EventLog.Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.source?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)
- [EventLogEntryType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlogentrytype?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)
- [EventLog.Entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entries?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-diagnostics-eventlog-entries)
- [EventLog.DeleteEventSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.deleteeventsource?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, here was what I ended up using:

```
public static class EventLogExtensions
{
    public static async Task<IList<EventRecord>> FindEventsAsync(this EventLog theLog, string queryString, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var query = new EventLogQuery(theLog.Log, PathType.LogName, queryString);
        var results = new List<EventRecord>();
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                    {
                                        using var reader = new EventLogReader(query);
                                        while (reader.ReadEvent() is { } ev)
                                        {
                                            results.Add(ev);
                                        }
                                    },
                                    token);
        return results;
    }
}
```

Usage for performing HealthCheck on EventLog access:

```
var aLog = new EventLog(_logName)
           {
               Source = _sourceName
           };

const int testEventId = UInt16.MaxValue - 757; // No special meaning, just a number for testing that 
                                               // is less than the max allowed EventId 65535

// Used to find this specific test message after write
var testData = Convert.ToHexString(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray());
var message = $"Event log health check test message -- ID[{testData}]";
aLog.WriteEntry(message,
                EventLogEntryType.Information,
                testEventId);
var queryString = $"*[EventData[Data and (Data='{message}')]]";
var eventRecords = await aLog.FindEventsAsync(queryString, cancellationToken);

return eventRecords.Count == 1
           ? HealthCheckResult.Healthy()
           : HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy("EventLog access is unhealthy, cannot write to EventLog.");
```